# Anchor Link has the correct URL but redirects to a completely different one on Apache / Nginx Server

Tags: apache, redirect, nginx, server

This question may be quite a shot in the dark because I'm new to server-side code, but the website I'm working on currently uses Apache / Nginx with Django and it runs into a very peculiar problem.

The site is [here](http://graphics.dailybruin.com/prime/recipes/) and whenever I click an article link on this page, it changes the base url, causing a 404. In this case it changes from graphics.dailybruin -> appletini.dailybruin. However, if I hover over the anchor tags, they have the right URL (graphics.dailybruin.~) so I find it very strange that I click them and then the URL changes.

I'm wondering how to diagnose this problem and where to look. Like whether I should be checking out the Django settings, or the server's nginx.conf file or etc.

In /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/appletini:

```
WSGIPythonPath /home/dailybruin/django
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName appletini.dailybruin.com
    ServerAlias *.appletini.dailybruin.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/appletini.dailybruin.log
    ServerSignature Off
    Options -Indexes

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/dailybruin/django/dailybruin.wsgi

    Alias /static/ /home/dailybruin/django/dailybruin/static/
    <Location "/static/">
            Options -Indexes
    </Location>
```

In /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/graphics:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName graphics.dailybruin.com
    ServerAlias *.graphics.dailybruin.com
    DocumentRoot /home/code/sites/graphics.dailybruin/
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/graphics.dailybruin.log
    ServerSignature Off
    Options -Indexes

    Alias /static/ /home/dailybruin/django/dailybruin/static/
    Alias /media/ /home/dailybruin/django/dailybruin/uploads/
    Alias /prime/winter-2014/coming-up-for-air/ /home/code/sites/prime-static/winter-2014/coming-up-for-air/
    Alias /prime/spring-2014/prime_hiking.jpg /home/code/sites/prime-static/spring-2014/prime_hiking.jpg
    Alias /prime/spring-2014/prime_panels.png /home/code/sites/prime-static/spring-2014/prime_panels.png
    Alias /prime/fall-2014/mental-health /home/code/sites/prime-static/fall-2014/mental-health/
    Alias /prime/winter-2015/mistress-of-magic /home/code/sites/prime-static/winter-2015/prime-magician/
    Alias /prime/winter-2015/los-angeles-2050 /home/code/sites/prime-static/winter-2015/prime-2050/
    Alias /prime/winter-2015/finding-beauty-in-biology /home/code/sites/prime-static/winter-2015/prime-bio
    WSGIScriptAlias /define-your-dorm /home/code/sites/graphics.dailybruin/define-your-dorm/dorm.wsgi

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg,
    LogLevel warn

</VirtualHost>


    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg,
    LogLevel warn

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please show your Apache and Nginx config.

Comment: @Alasdair so actually I don't think it has an nginx.conf file, I ran searches across the whole server and couldn't find anything. However, I did find in /etc/apache2 the sites-enabled and sites-available directories which contain files both titled appletini and graphics. Do you think I should modify those files to solve this problem?

Comment: Please show the contents of the `appletini` and `graphics` files.

Comment: @Alasdair updated with them just now.

Comment: I can't see anything in the graphic config that handles `/prime/recipes/` which is redirecting. What are the contents of `/home/code/sites/graphics.dailybruin/prime/recipes/`?

Comment: @Alasdair hm so there's actually no recipes directory in the prime folder. But inside prime I did find an .htaccess file which has a rewrite rule and I think that may be the culprit because it says: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://appletini.dailybruin.com/prime/$1 [P]

Comment: Sounds like you've found the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the rewrite rule in your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ appletini.dailybruin.com/prime/$1 [P]
```

This is redirecting all requests to the `appletini` subdomain.

If you want to stop the redirects, then remove the rule. Unfortunately, because it's a permanent redirect, visitor's browsers will cache the redirect so will still be redirected. Getting users to clear their caches is tricky, but there's not much else you can do.